# faulty install of Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.4

Windows7 with python 3.4 32bit.
Downloaded and ran install according to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101289/could-not-install-matplotlib).
However I have a different error, so I posted a new question.

I removed the faulty install and tried the installer from the sourceforge link off matplotlib.org. Both finish claiming to be successful, though testing results in an error (both resulting in the same error)

```
from matplotlib import *

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

Comment: Not sure how to tactfully deal with this question anymore but I worked around this error by installing Anaconda, an outstanding python kit which includes a panoply of extensions for python (including Matplotlib). It has worked flawlessly for me. I recommend it to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to install six. As given in [Python Error: "ImportError: No module named six"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222458/python-error-importerror-no-module-named-six)

Better you can install pip and install all libraries using that.

Comment: According to the question I referenced, the download should include all dependencies. Is there any reason 'six' is excluded? Is there any reason it was never mentioned in the MatPlotLib installation guide(http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html)? Just trying to gain a better understanding of the situation